# JourneyBuilder: Unsubscribe Decision Split

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, unsubscribe

What i am trying to achieve is an unsubscribe decision split that checks if a customer is unsubscribed directly against the global subscriber status.

Since i only can link dataextensions to the data designer, i feel kind of limited to get the "subscriber status" from the global subscriber status. For example the status of _Subscribers Dataview.

What i do not want is:
Creating SQL queries and dataextensions of system data views which i periodically update.

Is there any out of the box implementation for unsubscribe decision splits?

Answer (score 5):

You really need SQL Queries to get the data from the _subscribers Data View and link it to the entry Data Extension of the journey so you can check who of them unsubscribed or not.

Depending on the aim of the journey, you can also use measures to filter by unsubscribes from the main entry audience (no journey needed in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the advice but to be honest this does not solve it. As per definition of the question i do not want to have SQL automations running to achieve this. That's why i am not going to accept the answer. The main reason behind is that this question still stays unanswered because it is not answered.

Comment: I get your point but based on my reply, I just want to confirm that it is not possible to achieve that without using SQL queries or maybe via API

Comment: You are talking about filters, these filters only apply while injecting contacts into a journey. I talk about decision splits that have to happen on a particular time. I do have to set these prior to sending emails to achieve follow up update-contact activities to inform other departments. These departments would then know which information a customer has gotten and which not. The longer the journey is the worse is the filter at the beginning and not inside activities inside the journey.

Comment: I totally got your point at the beginning. I proposed the filter option as you didn't detail the aim of the journey and why you needed it. Now it is clear. Unfortunately, my suggestion is the same. I don't see any other approach rather than using SQL Queries. I hope someone from the community could suggest another approach.

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick one thing I can think of is a custom activity as decision split. This would be able to perform an api call against the subscriber status and route contacts accordingly. This is obviously development intensive and might need an external service to host the custom split activity.

Comment: Anyone here that is interested in teaching willing students to create a custom activity like this that can be freely shared in the salesforce ecosystem? Or should this be directly transferred into the IdeaExchange of Salesforce because this should be a standard functionality? I am just trying to get a good solution for other people that might need this funtionality.

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick I was actually thinking of making this a student project in my team because like you I was wondering why this doesn't work out of the box. We will discuss this in our sprint planning next week. I will keep you updated

Comment: @JahannesSchapdick This will be the next item I tackle in my new SFMC blog (invokerceate.dev). I'll be walking through the process of a creating a generic custom activity step-by-step along with a git repo that can be referenced at any time. Will try and have this up in the next week or two.